# TensorFlow Recommenders: InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,1] = 66521 is not in [0, 12976) [Op:ResourceGather]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommendation system using the TensorFlow Recommenders (TFRS), and I'm facing an issue while inferencing the trained model. I have created the Query and Candidate Towers and set the embedding dimension to be the length of unique movies in my dataset. The user features have already been normailzed.

```
class UserModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, users_vocab, embedding_dimension = 128):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.IntegerLookup(vocabulary=users_vocab),
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(users_vocab) + 2, embedding_dimension)
        ])

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Take the input dictionary, pass it through each input layer,
        # and concatenate the result.
        ret = tf.concat([
            self.user_model(inputs["USER_ID"]),
            tf.reshape(inputs["USER_FEATURE"], [-1, 1])
        ], axis=1)
        print(tf.shape(ret))
        return ret
```

After training when I try to get recommendations by creating index using the BruteForce Layer, and d is the dictionary containing UserId and User Features

```
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.query_model)
index.index(movie_features.batch(16192).map(model.candidate_model), movies)
_, titles = index(d, k=1)
```

My model recommends movies which are not there in my embedding vector space and throws this error when I try to get recommendations for k>1

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,1] = 66521 is not in [0, 12976) [Op:ResourceGather]
```

Whereas when I pass k=1, the model gives me a movie ID

```
recommendations for user [2471]: [Movie ID]
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank You! :)

**EDIT 1**: To add to the above problem, when I pass candidate features without the identifier `index.index(movie_features.batch(16192).map(model.candidate_model))` then my model returns indices correctly, but these indices values are greater than the length of movies variable.

movie_features: `<MapDataset shapes: {MOVIE_ID: (), MOVIE_FEATURE: ()}, types: {MOVIE_ID: tf.int32, MOVIE_FEATURE: tf.float64}>`

movies: list of unique movie id's `movies = training_data.MOVIE_ID.unique()` of length 83349